# How to change default landing page to login instead of index

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am pretty new to next.js and kind of stuck on basic issue.

here is my _app.js

```
class MyApp extends App {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.persistor = persistStore(props.store)
  }

  static async getInitialProps ({ Component, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {}

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps({ ctx })
    }

    return { pageProps }
  }

  render () {
    const { Component, pageProps, store } = this.props
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate
          loading={null}
          persistor={this.persistor}
        >
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default withRedux(createStore)(withReduxSaga(MyApp))
```

This is my index.js

```
function Home (props) {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className='home'>
          <Link href='/login'>
              <a>Go to Login</a>
            </Link>

            <h1>THIS IS HOME</h1>

        </div>
}
```

Currently when I start an app it lands on index page. 
How do I make this land on Login page directly?

Let me know if you need to see other files?

Comment: NextJS maps each page in the `pages` dir to a route, so, your browser is opens on `/` which is mapped to `index.js.

What do you mean by "land on Login"? you want to map `/` to `login.js` page?

Comment: Yes as per you explained, I want to map / to /login. Right now it opens on / page. I want to open /login when I load website.

Comment: you will need to work with custom server https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-express

Comment: when a user is already signed in, would you want them to see login page still?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the right way of doing things but I was able to navigate user on Login page instead of index page when website loads.

```
  // redirect user to login page
  useEffect(() => {
    Router.push('/login')
  })
  return (
    <div>  
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

In index.js import and export login page:

```js
import blog from "./login.js";

export default login;
```